# Framer/CoffeeScript - animate content fading in when mouse scrolled

Tags: javascript, scroll, coffeescript, prototypejs, framerjs

Is it possible to fade content in as the mouse scrolls using Coffeescript or Javascript in Framer?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Go through this lesson and you can see one method of how it can be accomplished

[Prototyping With Framer](https://speakerdeck.com/stakes/prototyping-with-framer)